# TypeError when assigning shallowly cloned object with a method that calls super

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm testing the following code in Chrome Canary 63 and on Chrome 61.  The goal of the code is to set a method that calls super onto a class instance (`z`).  In my codebase sometimes property blocks are cloned with Object.assign before being added to the instance and whenever this happens the code fails.

I've reproduced the problem with the code example below.  The code works fine if avoid the shallow clone (`props = Object.assign({}, props);`) but if I add that line I get `TypeError: (intermediate value).bar is not a function`.

I've tried doing `Object.create(this, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(props))` instead of `Object.assign` but it results in the same error.

Is there any way to properly set `super` on objects that have been cloned?

```
let Moo = class {
    bar() {
        return " [bar on Moo] ";
    }
};

let Zoo = class extends Moo { 
    bar() { 
        return " [bar on Zoo] " + super.bar();
    }
};

function addProps(inst, props) {
    // Code works if the line below is commented out but otherwise
    // results in TypeError: (intermediate value).bar is not a function
    props = Object.assign({}, props); // <-- Offending code

    Object.setPrototypeOf(props, inst.__proto__);
    Object.assign(inst, props);
}

let props = {
    onZooInst: {
        bar() {
            return " [bar on overridden instance] " + super.bar();
        }
    }
};

let z = new Zoo();
addProps(z, props.onZooInst);
console.log(z.bar());
```

Comment: What is purpose of `super.bar();`? Why do you use `class` expression to define `Moo` and `Zoo`?

Comment: I'm using ES6 syntax and purpose of super.bar() is to call the next method up in the prototype chain.

Comment: What is expected result of `return " [bar on overridden instance] " + super.bar();`? `" [bar on overridden instance] [bar on Moo] "`?

Comment: If only super were dynamic! I added your question to this ESDiscuss thread: https://esdiscuss.org/topic/the-super-keyword-doesnt-work-as-it-should#content-31

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone who may face the same problem I finally found a solution.

Instead of defining blocks of object literals like

```
let a = {
    someFunc() {
        super.someFunc();
    } 
}
```

You can replace them with an arrow function that returns them:

```
let a = () => {
    return {
        someFunc() {
            super.someFunc();
        } 
    }
};
```

this works because `a().someFunc !== a().someFunc` - in other words you get a new function and we *don't* need to resolve to dynamic code generation (eval/new Function).  You should safely be able to do `Object.setPrototypeOf` on the return value of `a()`.

Comment: Are you still using the same `addProps` function with your new arrow-function approach? Can you post the whole code for your answer?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any way to properly set `super` on objects that have been cloned?

Nope. `super` uses the function's `[[HomeObject]]` slot, which is set when the function (method) is created and cannot be changed at present.

Probably the best quote from the spec on this is in [Table 27](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#table-27):

> `[[HomeObject]]`: If the function uses `super`, this is the object whose [[GetPrototypeOf]] provides the object where `super` property lookups begin.

The only thing you could do is try to change the prototype of the object that the function's `[[HomeObject]]` refers to, but that A) Gets ugly ***fast***, and B) Kills performance (in those situations where it matters).

If you're doing lots of "method" cloning, you're better off using simple properties that refer to functions, not *methods*, and not using `super`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - but then why should the code work without the Object.assign?  I based my attempt off the MDN docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super#Using_super.prop_in_object_literals but it seems based on your explanation it doesn't give the full ins and outs.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out: Object.assign does not copy methods, it creates references to them.


And as you stated correctly, the [[HomeObject]] is set where the function is created.


So if I use Object.setPrototypeOf it has no impact on function references.  One way around it is to eval function.toString to create a new function, put it in an object and then call setPrototypeOf on it but that's a little too hackish to be useful and it blitzes any scope on the original function.

Comment: @Jarym: Nothing in JavaScript *copies* functions (other than using `toString` and `eval`, which often won't work), you're always dealing with references (as with other objects). `var f1 = function() { };` stores a *reference* to the function in `f1`. `var f2 = f1;` (which is essentially what `Object.assign` does) *copies* that reference to `f2`. `Object.setPrototypeOf` would indeed change the `bar` that gets called if applied to the correct object (https://jsfiddle.net/ym7zcow3/), but as I say, it gets ugly fast and kills the performance of the object. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If interpret requirement correctly you can adjust `bar` function at `props` object to `this.bar()` and use `Function.prototype.call()`, `Function.prototype.apply()` or `Reflect.apply()` to set `this` of function call to `props.onZooInst.bar` to `Moo.prototype`

```js
let Moo = class {
    bar() {
        return " [bar on Moo] ";
    }
};

let Zoo = class extends Moo { 
    bar() { 
        return " [bar on Zoo] " + super.bar();
    }
};

let props = {
    onZooInst: {
        bar() {
            return " [bar on overridden instance] " + this.bar();
        }
    }
};

let z = new Zoo();

let reflectBar = Reflect.apply(props.onZooInst.bar, z.__proto__, []);

let callBar = props.onZooInst.bar.call(z.__proto__);

console.log(reflectBar);

console.log(callBar);
```

Comment: Thanks, I know I can rewrite the code differently but I wanted to make super work.  I'm resigned to the fact that at the moment it is not possible to do that.